# Cannot find symbol, Java and Strings

Tags: java, string

I've tried tinkering around with this for awhile and have yet to figure out what its giving me this error. The code is far from complete but I'm just trying to figure out why it says it can't find variable ch1. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
 public class PhoneNumber {
    String phoneNumber;

    public PhoneNumber(String num) {
        phoneNumber = num;
    }

    public String decodePhoneNumber() {
        // Takes string form phone number and decodes based on number pad
        // Find code that makes if statement not care about caps
        // so if a || b || c number[cnt] = 1 etc..

        for (int cnt = 0; cnt < phoneNumber.length(); cnt++) {
            char ch1 = phoneNumber.charAt(cnt);
            if (Character.ch1.equalsIgnoreCase("a") || ("b") || ("c")) {

            } else if (ch1.equalsIgnoreCase("d" || "e" || "f")) {

            } else if (ch1.equalsIgnoreCase("j" || "k" || "l")) {

            } else if (ch1.equalsIgnoreCase("m" || "n" || "o")) {

            } else if (ch1.equalsIgnoreCase("p" || "q" || "r" || "s")) {

            } else if (ch1.equalsIgnoreCase("t" || "u" || "v")) {

            } else {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps it's the `Character.ch1` that's giving the error. Does the `Character` class have a ch1 variable? Also, would it be possible to give us the line number that the error occurs in?

Comment: It occurs on the "if (Character.ch1.equalsIgnoreCase ("a") || ("b") || ("c"))" line. I was reading up on trying to figure out how to fix another error i had and it said using Character.variableName would fix the problem I had but now I have another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make it work regardless of capital letters then you would need to normalize the input to lower case and then do the character comparison:

```
char ch1 = phoneNumber.toLowerCase().charAt(cnt);
if (ch1 == 'a' || ch1 == 'b' || ch1 == 'c') {
   // Do something
}
...
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up, made a huge difference and helped to fix my code!

Answer (score 2):

You have syntax errors and that is why you cannot find ch1.

Try modifying your code as per this syntax. These changes need to be done in all the conditionals.

```
if ((ch1 == 'a') || (ch1 == 'b') || (ch1 =='c')) {
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up, made a huge difference and helped to fix my code!